# I would like to add partials in meteor.js

Tags: meteor

Using a dir structure:

```
clients
    main.css
    main.html
    main.js
server
    main.js
imports
    ui
        partials
            header
                header.css
                header.html
                header.js
                header.collection.js
            body
                body.css
                body.html
                body.js
                body.collection.js
            footer
                footer.css
                footer.html
                footer.js
                footer.collection.js
```

in the client/main.html (via main.js)

I would like to create something like: (simplified)

```
{{headercontent}}
{{bodycontent}}
{{footercontent}}
```

What is the import structure to add these partials in main.js?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create these partials by creating different templates for each of them.

I will give a short example. Let's say we want to create a page(finalTemplate) with four component- 1)header,2 )footer, 3)Sidebar and 4) Content.

The structure you have made is good for these. You just need to be careful with importing the required files while writing the codes.

Just as a caution, the collections has to be imported in both server and client startup.

To include the four components in the fial you just need to include those templates.

so my final page will look like

```
<template name="finalTemplate">
  {{> header}}    //Templates are imported by {{> TemplateName}} Not by {{TemplateName}}
  {{> sidebar}}
  {{> content}}
  {{> footer}}
</template>
```

Example import structure for the example you asked for:
**header.js**

```
import './header.html'
import './header.css'
import '.header.collections.js'
```

In startup function for server, you should import all collections files as they are needed on server side.

Comment: does template name=finaltemplate go into main.html or into header.html. if in header, how is main set us...

Comment: `main.html` . All code in the client folder are loaded but nothing is loaded from the imports folder until it is called(or imported). So, if you include it into 'header.html' the code will never load.

Comment: Thanks alot for the advice, I'm now off and running!